# Executing Java and C# within the same process?

Tags: java, c#, memory

I want to execute a Java VM and a C# application within the same process making it possible to share the same memory region along with the same memory for the same shared libraries.

Does anyone know a way to do that?

I would be able to run Java from C# or C# from Java or even using a C application to start both within the same process.

[Update]

The http://jni4net.com/ project claims to provide the Feature: "Intraprocess - it means that both VMs are in same process. Any call uses same thread and same stack for both environments. It's relatively fast."

This is exactly what I try to do myself in order to use a simple off-heap memory address and use it to both intra-process VMs.

Comment: Can you pl. elaborate on what is the motivation to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/)?

Comment: Not exactly. I updated the question to show an example library claiming to have done just that (intra-process Java and c# VMs running in the same process).

Comment: It sounds like what you really just want is a shared-memory segment.

Comment: The motivation is simply using a single malloc and provide C# and Java with the address to use so both access the same memory region without delay or any other unspecified behavior as it happens with memory mapped files for instance. 

The ideas is to write parts of an application in C# and in Java as the Framework I want to use is only available for C# but the application is mostly in Java.

Comment: @chrylis I want to avoid shared-memory segments as they are not platform independent and as I have not figured out how to use non-persistent mapped shared memory regions in Java. It appears to me to have both VMs living in the same process is more beneficial (both VMs would die instantly if the process dies etc)

Comment: @MartinKersten I think you should elaborate more on the problem you are trying to solve.  Java at least has a large pain threshold when needing to talk to other programs outside the JVM  (except through network communication), which you need to outweigh with the advantages of your outlined solution.

Comment: I still think your cleaner shot is mmfs. That library does not strike me as current and too prone to holes. The risk of unspecified behavior is big with a lot of runtime back and forth. It seems that the .net assembly has a bunch of static java signatures

Comment: The magic is using the jvm.dll / libjvm.so and invoking / starting the Java VM using a loaded shared library instead of spawning a new process and loading a full application. That's how the process is shared. Mapping an actual file will kill me since I need to sync gigabytes of data and therefore accessing a temp file is a killer.

Comment: Alternatively I could use a ram drive (potential duplication of ram) or I manage a platform dependent C lib providing a region of non-persisted shared memory on Linux, Windows and Mac. Running Java in the same process would be solve any problems. Mapping to a file has also the problem that there is no guarantee when and where the change is reflected by the other process and there is no guarantee that two changes happen in the exact order (which basically is for shared memory but surely is for in process memory)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to embed Java and Mono within the same process. There are resources available for doing so within a C/C++ application but it is not limited to C/C++.

By embedding Java and Mono (C#) together within the same process, all the desired properties can be guaranteed. There is no duplication in the shared memory, memory manipulation is instantaneously and the changes appear in the correct order.

One should take care to pin the threads according to the memory domain in multiple processor setups as always but thats about it.

It is even possible to share the same processor by pinning the threads of C# and Java to the same processor and to profit from second level and even third level caches.

Another important benefit is both VMs profit from sharing the same local shared library instance resulting in code running in either of the VMs interacting with the very same library instance instead of using two distinct versions.

Helpful information:

- [For Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html)
- [For Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/)

Answer (score 0):

C# is .NET which is compiled to an Intermediary Language (IL), it is possible that Java has a processor for the .NET IL, but it would be need to be included as part of the Java project when built.

You would not be able to run two separate processes that share the same execution thread and memory.

Comment: I updated the question to provide an example of what I try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is I don't think this is a good idea.

From my personal experience, all the currently available projects which claimed to support both are having various defects and support issues on libraries and even some language features, not to even mention the run-time performance. If you don't prefer a simple socket solution or a memory mapped file stuff and declare them to be non-standard and with pitfalls, then I could only tell you the frameworks you trying to use are with even more pitfalls.

Plus, the idea of sharing memory is a bit puzzling me. What exact data piece are you trying to share? Bear in mind that the C# and Java memory structure are not mutually compatible, you either storing some stuff with 3rd party standard e.g. audio/video/pictures etc; or you need to write your own serialization layer which essentially disable you from being able to operate on the same object from both sides. If you are already writing your own serialization layer, what blocks you from using a socket solution which seems best supported from both side to me?

If there is any performance concern, I could say that since you are using Java + C# solution, the performance difference between MMF, socket or shared memory is insignificant compared to whatever performance your application can possibly achieve. If your application really requires such a performance, you'd better do it in C++ or even ANSI C.

So I totally agree with all the comments, that the stuff you are trying to achieve seems not in the right direction.

Comment: It is acceptable to disagree but if you want to keep like 60 GB of memory in sync it would mean to duplicate it. Also what I do (I found the solution) is supported directly by Oracle and also Mono. There is no gap, hole or whatsoever. Again memory mapped files have a hard problem that means it might be duplicated in memory and the way it is synced is unspecified as in potentially different for each platform. There is no guarantee of timely order.

Comment: Firstly it's very hard to believe your program is simultaneously operating on 60GB of data in a random access way. And you always have stuff like cross box shared in memory data you can use e.g. coherence cache, if you are forced to keep all in memory. Seeing your solution below with `Mono` I can only wish you good luck. As I've seen more than a dozen of stuff which claim they can do it in this or that way but all ends up hopelessly buggy. Good luck man.

Comment: I am working in the enterprise sector as a contractor. When I say I need this, I need this. 60GB is by the way nothing today (we add 512GB RAM today on default). I need it for running physical simulations.

Integrating a JVM or Mono in a process is a requirement these tools live up to for 20/15 years. I just never did this myself. We are engineers, we test extensively on multiple platforms. That's what we live for. We run on science not on luck :)

Comment: IMHO platforms like this gives you more bugs than you could possibly fix within your project life cycle. However seems you've decided I could only wish you best luck :)

Comment: It is absolutely stable so far. I even did crazy things and the VMs are not interfering with each other. I really start to like it! It is way more easy to develop a C like algorithm in C# thanks to pointer support and alike. On the other hand Java is superior when it comes to class file handling and profiling - at least I might lack the experience when it comes to C#.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to host a JVM in a .NET process, or to host a .NET CLR in a Java process, but they are ugly and require familiarity with JNI (Java Native Interface) and/or the CLR's COM-based hosting API.

There are fortunately interoperability tools that encapsulate these mechanisms and allow Java and .NET to run in the same process and freely interoperate.  One such tool is JNBridgePro from JNBridge.  Please see www.jnbridge.com for more information, and particularly look for "shared memory."

Disclaimer: I am with JNBridge.